# Is it possible to use a slice in a query?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selection

Let's say I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(range(5)), 'B': ['X_abc', 'Y_abc', 'abc', 'foo', 'Y_abc']})
```

and I want to query for a certain value in column `B`, I can use `query` like this:

```
target = 'Y_abc'

df_ss = df.query('B == @target')
```

which yields

```
   A      B
1  1  Y_abc
4  4  Y_abc
```

as expected.

I am now wondering whether there is an option to use a slice, so e.g. something like this:

```
df_ss2 = df.query('B == @target[2:]')
```

This does not work and returns

> ValueError: "slice" is not a supported function

I can of course use

```
df_ss3 = df.loc[df['B'] == target[2:]]
```

which gives the expected output

```
   A    B
2  2  abc
```

but I am wondering whether I could achieve the same using `query`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [5]: s = slice(2, None)

In [6]: target[s]
Out[6]: 'abc'

In [7]: df.query('B == @target[@s]')
Out[7]: 
   A    B
2  2  abc
```

But really, why not just

```
df_ss2 = df.query('B == "%s"' % target[2:])
```

(or variations using format specifiers or f-strings)? Pushing any calculation into the string to make it implicitly evaluated rather than explicitly evaluated will have a lot of downsides, but I can't see many upsides besides syntactic sugar.

Comment: Interesting: `df.query('B == @target[@s]')` gives me `ValueError: unknown type object` - what is your Pandas version? PS I like the simplicity of your second solution! +1

Comment: Pandas version 0.20.3.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following hack:

```
In [73]: df.query("B == @re.sub(r'^.{2}','', @target)")
Out[73]:
   A    B
2  2  abc
```

alternatively you can write a small helper function:

```
In [90]: def my_slice(s, start=0, stop=None, step=None):
    ...:     return s[start:stop:step]
    ...:

In [91]: my_slice(target, 2)
Out[91]: 'abc'

In [92]: df.query("B == @my_slice(@target,2)")
Out[92]:
   A    B
2  2  abc
```